# Explicit conversion of datetime2 to timestamp in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am working with a query in SQL Server:

```
select datetimevalue 
from temp;
```

Here datetimevalue column's datatype is `datetime2` and I need to convert this value into ***timestamp***.

In MySQL if I simply write:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAM(datetimevalue) 
from temp;
```

then it returns timestamp.

Is there any way to convert datetime in timestamp explicitly in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: yes but i don't want to create any function. i just find is there any inbuilt function like mysql

Comment: @Amit thanks i will do with the way you suggest thank you

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't have a `timestamp` type. It used to have one in old versions but that type **IS NOT** a date & time value. In current versions `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`.